# Converting Select list to Jquery UI Autocomplete

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, xhtml

I have the following select box I am replacing with Jquery autocomplete:

```
<select name="selectarea" onchange="findCity(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" id="sel" />
```

The Jquery UI autocomplete code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#sel" ).autocomplete({
            source: "xml/states.php"
    });

    $( "#sel"  ).autocomplete('option','minLength',0);

    $( "#sel"  ).bind("click", function(event, ui) { 
    $( "#sel"  ).autocomplete( "search" , '' );

    }); 

});
```

Problem is I don't know where to place the call to the "findCity" javascript in the Jquery code. The json response it is receiving is from a php file and the array looks like this:

```
$STATES = array("scAllBusinesses"=>"All Businesses", 
"scAppraisals"=>"Appraisals", 
"scArchitect"=>"Architect", 
"scArtGallery"=>"Art Gallery", 
"scAttorney"=>"Attorney", 
"scBallet"=>"Ballet", 
"scBanks"=>"Banks", 
"scBar"=>"Bar",
);
```

The autocomplete works fine and populates, just not sure where to place the javascript call (findCity). Any assistance is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the change event of autocomplete. [From the jquery ui documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default):

> Triggered when the field is blurred, if the value has changed; ui.item
>   refers to the selected item.
>
> Code examples
>
> Supply a callback function to handle the change event as an init
>   option.

```
   $( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   change: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Bind to the change event by type: autocompletechange.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "autocompletechange", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: The javascript code of findCity(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value); is for a select box and not sure what code to use for the autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is you need to add a select handler to the options passed to autocomplete like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#sel" ).autocomplete({
        source: "xml/states.php",
        minLength: 0,

        select: function(event, ui) {
            findCity(ui);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Have attempted to use the following code: $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#sel" ).autocomplete({
                source: "xml/states.php"
        });
  
  $( "#sel"  ).autocomplete('option','minLength',0);

  $( "#sel"  ).bind("click", function(event, ui) { 
  $( "#sel"  ).autocomplete( "search" , '' );
  });
  
  $( "#sel" ).bind( "autocompletechange", function(event, ui) {
    findCity(ui);
  });
  
    }); The javascript I am attempting to fire is a switch statement: function findCity(which)
 {
    if (which != 0) 
    {
      switch(which)
      {